# export certificate using powershell

Tags: powershell, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, export

Any experts know what code needs to be done to export cert's values from keyusage in cert detail tab?

[image]

the codes

```
dir cert:\currentuser\my |
Where-Object  ($_.Extensions `
  | Where-Object { $_.Oid.Value -eq "2.5.29.15" -And ( $_.KeyUsages -eq 'KeyEncipherment|DataEncipherment(30)') } |
Foreach-Object { [system.IO.file]::WriteAllBytes("c:\export\$($_.SerialNumber).cer",   ($_.Export('CERT', $null)) ) }
```

Comment: How to add an inline image.  Copy and paste in the body. Windows has an inbuilt hotkey (Win + Shift + S) which executes Snipping Tool. Any screen captured will be copied to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to list all certificates that contain **ONLY** `KeyEncipherment` in Key Usage Extension:

```bsh
#Listing 1
dir cert:\currentuser\my | 
Where-Object {
  ($_.Extensions | 
  Where-Object{ 
    $_.Oid.Value -eq "2.5.29.15" -and $_.KeyUsages -eq "KeyEncipherment"}) } | 
Select-Object{ 
  $_.SerialNumber, 
  $_.Issuer, 
  ($_.Extensions | 
    Where-Object{ $_.Oid.Value -eq "2.5.29.15" }).KeyUsages }
```

And here the export:

```bsh
#Listing 2
dir cert:\currentuser\my | 
Where-Object { 
  ($_.Extensions | 
    Where-Object{ 
      $_.Oid.Value -eq "2.5.29.15" -and $_.KeyUsages -eq "KeyEncipherment"}) } | 
Foreach-Object{ 
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes(
  ".\$($_.SerialNumber).cer", 
  $_.Export("Cert", $null)); }
```

Try this to list all certificates that contain **ONLY** `DataEncipherment` **AND** `KeyEncipherment` in Key Usage Extension:

```bsh
#Listing 3
dir cert:\currentuser\my | 
Where-Object {
  ($_.Extensions | 
  Where-Object{ 
    $_.Oid.Value -eq "2.5.29.15" -and $_.KeyUsages -eq "DataEncipherment, KeyEncipherment"}) } | 
Select-Object{ 
  $_.SerialNumber, 
  $_.Issuer, 
  ($_.Extensions | 
    Where-Object{ $_.Oid.Value -eq "2.5.29.15" }).KeyUsages }
```

And here the export:

```bsh
#Listing 4

dir cert:\currentuser\my | 
Where-Object { 
  ($_.Extensions | 
    Where-Object{ 
      $_.Oid.Value -eq "2.5.29.15" -and $_.KeyUsages -eq "DataEncipherment, KeyEncipherment"}) } | 
Foreach-Object{ 
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes(
  ".\$($_.SerialNumber).cer", 
  $_.Export("Cert", $null)); }
```

To check the key usages values of ALL certificates run:

```bsh
#Listing 5
dir cert:\currentuser\my | 
Select-Object{  
  $_.SerialNumber, 
  $_.Issuer, 
 ($_.Extensions | Where-Object{ $_.Oid.Value -eq "2.5.29.15" }).KeyUsages }
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:13 char:63
+ ... ect { [system.IO.file]::WriteAllBytes("c:\export\$($_.Subject).cer",  ...
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull                                         i got this error. any help? it null-valued expression

Comment: hmm will it be  possible to list out the 3 values base on the img description? also, i am kinda new here, what does oldvalue means and why it is required?

Comment: The first script does show `serial number`, `issuer`, and the `key usages`. Where or what is `oldvalue`?

Comment: $_.Oid.Value -eq "2.5.29.15 this i mean :)

Comment: sorry possible to modify the codes slightly, i am generating a new cert and getting this two values  Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment (30), so in the system i have to pull these two values from keyusage and export the certs out..

Comment: thanks daniel, i just tried your latest export code, i stlil not able to export any certs out.

Comment: would you please remove the entirely unneeded backticks? they are both hard to see and too easy to leave behind when editing. almost every "more to come" step in a PoSh script allows line wrapping without the nastiness of backticks. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey The `-and` as well as `-eq` and so on need it, but I did you the favor.

Comment: thanks guys i have accepted the answer. great!! it works. anyway i have posted a similar question related to cert export. would appreciate it :)

Comment: @DanielFisherlennybacon - thank you! it reads so much more smoothly ... [*grin*]